# How to make model, django

Tags: python, django, model

I need to make Django model for this structure:

[image]
Exercise has only name and text... In one lesson must be 10 exercises.
To my mind, we need 1 table lessons and 1 table exercises:

```
class Lessons(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField()


class Exercises(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    text = models.CharField()
```

And here I don`t know how to link 1 lesson with 10 exercises.

In which way I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to make a relation between Exercices and Lessons,

There's an example:

```
class Lessons(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Exercises(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lessons)
    name = models.CharField()
    text = models.CharField()
```

It makes sense that an exercise belongs to a lesson.